# Inflation parameter value

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, cosmological-inflation

One of slow-roll Inflation condition is
$$ \ddot{\phi} \ll H\dot{\phi}. $$

When i performed numeric calculation, I got a value:
$$ \ddot{\phi} = -2,  \\ H\dot{\phi} = -120. $$

I got confused because as I know that negative value which near to zero is bigger than negative value far from zero (e.g:  -0.1 > -10).
So, from my calculation above, the condition does not hold true?

But, if we absolute both value
$$ \left|(\ddot{\phi} )\right| \ll \left|(H\dot{\phi} )\right| ,  $$
then slow-roll inflation condition is hold true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, absolute values should be considered. This condition is also written in the form
$$
|\eta_H|=\left|\frac{\ddot{\phi}}{H\dot\phi}\right|\ll 1
$$
which is called the (second) Hubble slow-roll parameter (the first one being $\epsilon_H=\frac{\dot\phi^2}{2H^2}$).

Comment: Thank you, sir.